# What is the reason for the speedup of transformer-xl?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, attention-mechanism, transformer

The inference speed of transformer-xl is faster than transformer.

Why?

If state reuse is the reason, so it is compared by two 32seq_len + state-reuse vs one 64seq_len + no-state-reuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For vanilla Transformer language models (Al Rfou et al), you process [1 2 3 4], predict 5, process [2 3 4 5], predict 6, and repeat.

For a Transformer-XL language model, you process [1 2 3 4], predict [5 6 7 8], predict [9 10 11 12], and repeat. Note that we don't have to reprocess [5 6 7 8] when predicting [9 10 11 12], because the representations can be reused.

https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/01/transformer-xl-unleashing-potential-of.html